# filepicker in IE10 and IE11 browse file makes page unresponsive

Tags: internet-explorer, filepicker.io

this is my first question ever asked on Stackoverflow: Using the filepicker jQuery library - IE9 works great, but in IE10 and IE11 if the "Choose File" button is pushed and a picture gets uploaded that way then the rest of the form/page is unresponsive for at least a minute no matter the size of the image. After that minute wait time people can type into the form on the page and type into input fields, but not before. However if I drag and drop an image into the dialogue window then the rest of the form/page works great (no lag/unresponsiveness).

Through testing: IE9 works great, other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) seem to work fine. IE11's debugger doesn't tell me anything useful.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so how did you solve it?

From what I'm seeing it looks like the code (we use filepickers version through their API

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>
```

) is implemented correctly (though it is being pulled onto the page with DOJO).

Some of our code is proprietary/intellectual property which I'm pretty sure I'd get into trouble if I posted it. Just looking out in the wild to see if anyone else has this problem and if they've solved it and how.

Comment: FIlepicker dialog is supported [back to IE8](https://developers.filepicker.com/docs/support/general/121). Your issue might be related to specific implementation. Do you have any production site when it can be tested?

Comment: I figured it out, if you find similar questions which are IE specific with any pages which use third party stuff (including analytics/tracking stuff etc.) my answer may prove useful. Thank you kindly for your reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was two separate issues tag teaming against IE10 and IE11.

1). With everything going on and with FilePicker's "Choose File" option there **seemed** to be some latency in letting mousedowns return true (for some reason they behaved as return false). Since I don't control the API and can only partially look at the code which is returned I'm using the word "seemed".

And 2). With third party tracking stuff added on the page with a lot of console.blah's involved this caused IE10 and IE11 to lag. (Console isn't available to IE10 and IE11 until the debugger panel is open).

The solution which worked like a charm for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('input[type="text"]').on("mousedown", function(){
            this.select();
            return true;
        });
        if(!window.console) {
            var console = {
                debug : function(){},
                dir : function(){},
                log : function(){},
                warn : function(){},
                error : function(){},
                time : function(){},
                timeEnd : function(){}
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

These two combined allowed the other input fields for IE10 and IE11 to perform as quickly as they do in IE9, FF, Chrome.